# Are Dutch companies obligated to pay employee's local transportation expenses?

Tags: netherlands, labour-law

A friend told me that there is a Dutch law obligate companies to handle the transportation expenses, Is that true or it is one of the company benefits and by agreement.

Kindly if there is something like that to provide a link.

Comment: Transportation for what; using public transport to and from work, reimbursement for business travel expense? Look at [this link](http://www.iamexpat.nl/read-and-discuss/expat-page/articles/wkr-new-rules-reimbursing-employee-expenses-netherlands) and see whether that could be what your friend means.

Comment: @Dorothy yes to and from work with business card, is that an optional thing or not ?

Comment: I don't know whether you know how to go to chat, so, yes you do have to pay; you are misunderstanding it completely. You pay for the tram, bus, train, whatever you use to go and from to work. The company DOES NOT have to pay for YOUR transportation. And I've removed my chatty bits; we don't do that on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the correct answer is in a comment, and the poster seems to misunderstand it: No, there is no legal obligation for a company in the Netherlands to pay the employee's transport cost for going from home to work and back from work to home.

A company *may* pay that cost, and that payment will be tax free.

Information can be found at http://www.iamexpat.nl/read-and-discuss/expat-page/articles/wkr-new-rules-reimbursing-employee-expenses-netherlands and (in Dutch) at http://www.werkkostenregeling-wkr.nl (thanks to Dorothy).

Comment: Thanks; we went back and forth, and I removed my comments as I thought it was adding to OP's confusion. Here are the links, if you'd like to add them to your answer, which I'll upvote (and then delete my comment). http://www.iamexpat.nl/read-and-discuss/expat-page/articles/wkr-new-rules-reimbursing-employee-expenses-netherlands http://www.werkkostenregeling-wkr.nl/

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you added that companies (at least for white-collar workers) usually *do* pay that cost.

Comment: @gerrit In my experience (6 jobs), usually in an addition to the bare salary, and not always fully covering the costs.